# Escaping curly brace in liquibase migration

Tags: jdbc, liquibase

I have a liquibase migration that includes braces {}. JDBC interprets these braces as escape sequences. How do I escape them so they are treated as literal curly braces?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that a question mark anywhere inside of the migration will turn liquibase's escaping off, so adding the following no-op comment code fixes the issue (that's some great code there liquibase ;) :

```
-- ?
```

Comment: Why not raise an issue and perhaps it will be fixed? https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE